# How to find duplicate records in database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has employee and another which has state.

I want to find the duplicate employee for each state.

**My code:**

```
SELECT 
    mem.Employee AS emp,  COUNT(*) AS dupeCount     
FROM 
    MEMtable AS mem 
INNER JOIN 
    RTable AS Routing ON mem.MemberID = Routing.MemberKey 
GROUP BY 
    mem.employee
HAVING  
    COUNT(*)>1
```

For same two table I have to again find the state which do not have any employee.

```
 SELECT routing.state AS empt     
 FROM MEMtable AS mem 
 INNER JOIN RTable AS Routing ON mem.MemberID = Routing.MemberKey 
 WHERE mem.employee IS NULL
```

Comment: This should indentify all duplicate rows. What is your question?

Comment: yes all duplicate employee against sate

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Routing.[State],mem.Employee AS emp, COUNT(*) AS dupeCount 
FROM MEMtable AS mem 
INNER JOIN RTable AS Routing ON mem.MemberID =Routing.MemberKey 
GROUP BY Routing.[State],mem.employee HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

As you asked for you second question in comments.
Its very simple just check Routing.MemberKey is null, No need to join other table, if you case in only to select data from RTable

```
SELECT routing.state    
 FROM RTable AS Routing  
 WHERE ISNULL(Routing.MemberKey,'')=''
```

Comment: can you answer to my second question also,First one worked great

Comment: I have edit my answer please check it for you second Q

Comment: Please edit you question, but here i uderstand that you asking, select state from Rtable which donot have any employee (Is it correct?). If you asking something else then please edit your question

Comment: thanks a lot for the help,can you tell me the query for: List of those blanket employee with one location, but are attached to every state

Comment: Is RTable.MemberKey is a foriegn Key of MEMtable.

Comment: Please explain location??

Comment: if you still in search, then please share your tables structure and and and ur required output in table form. then you will get proper answers according to your situation. because your second question have confusion... thanks

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you all the employee that are more than one.

```
SELECT
 Routing.[State],mem.Employee AS emp, Count(*) as NoOfRecord
FROM MEMtable AS mem 
INNER JOIN RTable AS Routing ON mem.MemberID =Routing.MemberKey 
GROUP BY Routing.[State],mem.employee
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the States which have no employee, you need a *complete list of states*. Your tables appear to be "**mem**" (a list of employees) and "**routing**" (a list of states with employees). You don't have a list of all states, regardless of whether there are employees or not.

For example:

**MEM**:

```
 - memberid=100, emp=John
 - memberid=200, emp=Bob
 - memberid=300, emp=Frank
```

**ROUTING**:

```
 - memberkey=200, state=California
 - memberkey=300, state=Kansas
 - memberkey=100, state=Michigan
```

Can you answer the question: "How many employees are in New York?" *No, because there is no ROUTING row for New York.*

If your ROUTING table contains an entry for New York, what would the memberKey be?

```
 - memberkey=???, state=NewYork
```

So you can find out how many employees are in each state where you have at least one employee in that state. But you cannot find out which states have no employees because you have no record for a state unless you have at least one employee in that state.

**EDIT**:

If we assume that every state is listed at least once in the ROUTING table (perhaps with memberkey set to NULL or some non-existent employee id), then you would look for any state in the ROUTING table that does not have a matching employee in the MEM table. The LEFT JOIN is used for this purpose:

```
  SELECT Routing.state, 
          count(mem.MemberID) empCount 
   FROM RTable Routing
   LEFT JOIN MEMTable mem
     ON mem.MemberID = Routing.MemberKey
   GROUP by mem.state
   HAVING count(mem.MemberID) = 0;
```

Explanation:

The query returns a count of employees for each state in ROUTING table. The ROUTING table is matched to the MEM table. By using the LEFT JOIN operator, the mem.MemberID column will return a NULL value if there is no match, and it will return the normal value if there is a match. The COUNT() function will only count non-null values. Therefore, if a state has no matches, the COUNT will be zero. This is tested with the HAVING clause after the data is grouped by state and the counts are taken. Any state with a count of zero will have no employees.

This will not account for states that are not listed in the ROUTING table at all.

Comment: but that is the requirement

Answer (score 0):

try this for second question

```
SELECT routing.state AS empt     
 FROM MEMtable AS mem 
 RIGHT JOIN RTable AS Routing ON mem.MemberID =Routing.MemberKey 
 where mem.employee is null
```

Comment: this is right but what if against state let ABC there are 2 records one have employee and other do not have so it is showing the record in the result

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your second Q....

```
SELECT routing.state AS empt     
 FROM  RTable AS Routing  
 LEFT JOIN  MEMtable AS mem ON mem.MemberID =Routing.MemberKey 
 where mem.employee is null
```